# How to re-use a value that is obtained in one Scala object into another?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, object, structure, project

I am trying to re-use an RDD that I am computing in one object into some other object. What I want is to form the RDD only once and then re-use it again and again.

For instance, if I have an object BB.scala and I am creating the RDD in it, what is the best way to save this RDD and use it again in a different object eg. ABC?

```
object BB{
    ....
    val myRDD = ....
 }

object ABC{
    myRDD.groupByKey() //How to use myRDD here?
 }
```

Please note that I want the object BB to run only once, while object ABC will run many times. Also, for now my application doesnt have a main, and I am running the objects using extends App. I am a beginner in Scala (and programming), please pardon me if this is something very basic.

Thanks.

Comment: On normal Scala what you did is enough to _"reuse"_ the value. However, since this is an **Spark** `RDD´, which is _lazy_, it will recompute every time you use it. In order to ensure only one computation you can `.cache()` your rdd in your VAL declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Since you declared `BB` as an `object` (which is a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)), you can access it very easily like this:

```scala
object BB{
    ....
    val myRDD = ....
 }

object ABC{
    val bbRDD = BB.myRDD.groupByKey() 
 }
```

I am not entirely sure what you want say when you say you want the

> object BB to run only once

but maybe you should consider using `class` or `case class` instead of `object` for some of your code, so you can instantiate them, like e.g.:

```scala
class BB {
    ....
    val myRDD = ....
 }

object ABC {
    val bb = new BB()
    val bbRRD = bb.myRDD.groupByKey()
 }
```